# Save All Post Permalink From A Specific Category into a .txt file

Tags: posts, functions, categories

Please I want to achieve a Goal of Saving Post Permalink In a .txt file From a Specific Category, Example; when a post is publish in a Specific category, it will save the post permalink in a .txt file in my root domain.

Below is the code I have so far.

```
function custom_update_txt_file( $post_id ) {
     $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id ) . "\r\n";
     $fp = fopen( get_home_path() . '/post-links.txt', 'a' );
     fwrite( $fp, $post_url );
     fclose( $fp );
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'custom_update_txt_file' );
```

Please Is there anyway this can be done using theme function or something similar, I am a novice in wp coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function [`in_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/) to check if the post is in some specific category.

And better check if the url already exists so you won't have multiple records with the same url.

```
function custom_update_txt_file( $post_id, $post ) {
    // Check if post is in category you can check by term_id or slug or array
    if(in_category( 'uncategorized', $post_id )) {
        $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id ) . "\r\n";
        $fp = fopen( ABSPATH . '/post-links.txt', 'a+' );

        $url_exists = false;

        // Read each line to check if the url already exists.
        while (($line = fgets($fp)) !== false) {
            $url_exists = ($line == $post_url) ? true : false;
        }

        if(!$url_exists) {
            fwrite( $fp, $post_url );
        }

        fclose( $fp );
    }
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'custom_update_txt_file', 10, 2 );
```

Another thing if you want to run this only one time when the post status is changed to publish and not everytime the post is update with the status publish.

Then better use the [`transition_post_status`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/) hook. You can check with it if the post status is changed and then do something.